# How to compile and run a C program on my android device through my PC terminal.?

Tags: android, c++, c, gcc, ssh

I want to compile and run a C program on my android device with my PC terminal through SSH.

I've already been able to install gcc on my device by using 'termux' application.  I compiled and run a c file on my device successfully.

I have rooted my device successfully.

I'm using terminal to access my files on my device by using SSHdroid application. I've been able to access my gcc directory and add it to my PATH through my SSH connection.

Although the 'gcc' command is being recognized by the system path but when I try to compile a c program I get this error:

```
cpp: error trying to exec '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/libexec/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/6.1.0/cc1': execv: Permission denied
```

I've already logged in SSHDroid as the root. I also can't run 'su' because of the same permission issue. Any idea why this is happening?

(I don't know how to install and run programs through SSHDroid)

Answer (score 0):

Try [running a native SSH server from Termux](https://oliverse.ch/tech/2015/11/06/run-an-ssh-server-on-your-android-with-termux.html) and see if that works (you will run as the normal Termux app user, so it avoids permission problems due to being a different user).